# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Not sure why this is happening here, I am getting this error from my component:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'timezone_offset' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SettingsComponent.html:16)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14377)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13513)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:13816)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13509)
at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
```

Interestingly enough it still displays the correct string in the template and there are no errors in ng-cli. Here is the code for the component producing the error:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetProfileService } from '../../services/get-profile.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-settings',
    templateUrl: './settings.component.html'
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    results: any;
    profile: any;

    constructor(private getProfileService: GetProfileService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getProfileService.profileAPI().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results = data
                this.profile = this.results
                console.log(this.profile)
            }
        );

    }

}
```

I am for now just using `{{ profile.timezone_offset }}` as the only thing on my template...

Comment: Please show your template. May be due to asynchronous operation, you are getting that error. Try `{{ profile?.timezone_offset }}`.

Comment: Have you tried `{{ profile?.timezone_offset }}` ?

Comment: yes that seemed to fix the issue. would you mind explaining to me what the ? does

Comment: @SandraWillford I have added some explanation in my answer. Please do check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your data has not been loaded within the `profile` object at the time when it was rendered. Only after the completion of asynchronous operation data is set within the `profile` object. `?.` should be used when your object is operating on asynchronous call. `timezone_offset` will be evaluated only when the `profile` object is defined.

Due to asynchronous operation, you might be getting that error. Try the following

`{{ profile?.timezone_offset }}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `?.` [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) <= documentation

```
{{ profile?.timezone_offset }}
```

It checks if `profile` exists before trying to access values from it. This is usefull if `profile` is loaded asynchronous.